# Can I debug an Android Wear app on an Android smartphone? (and how)

Tags: android, debugging, android-4.4-kitkat, wear-os

I'm planning to create myself a proof of concept Android Wear application, but I'm not planning to buy myself an Android smartwatch yet. I will buy it if I get positive reactions from my target audience once I show some of them the proof of concept app from my personal smartphone (Android Kitkat).

is it possible to run/debug an Android Wear application on my smartphone? Suggestions for third party software is welcome as well.

Comment: Do you really need to show your proof of concept on a smartphone? Wouldn't an [emulator](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#SetupEmulator) on a desktop/laptop suffice?

Comment: For me it does, I would like to take my smartphone outside and show it to people on the streets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a demo/proof of concept I'd say yes it's possible, in certain conditions/restrictions:

1. It should be a standalone/fullscreen app (it will be hard to emulate the notifications/cards behaviour)
2. Define a 320x320px layout for your content (or 280x280, and eventually add a round mask it you need a round watch)
3. Code like it's Android!

Note that behind the scene communication between the phone and the app will be different when you do it on a real Wear, but for a demo your audience will not see the difference.

You can check [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.murphy2712.doctorwear) in which I use a similar layout for the watch, the handheld app and the widgets.